# How to organize reducers and actions in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I feel like theres probably an easier / better way than how Im doing it. Im just trying to simplify the file organization. Im going in circles with import errors, the latest is : Uncaught ReferenceError: visibilityFilter is not defined at Object.defineProperty.value

index.js :

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'))
```

And in App.js :

```
var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

import Header from './Header'
import Footer from './Footer'

//material-ui imports here... (removed for conciseness)

//////////// REDUX RELATED //////////
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import * as reducers from '../reducers/reducer'

let store = createStore(reducers.rootReducer)

// Log the initial state
//console.log(store.getState())

let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => 
  console.log(store.getState())
)

// Dispatch some actions

store.dispatch(setOwner('Admin'))

// ...components removed for brevity...
```

And finally in reducer.js

```
/*
* action creators
*/

// action types
const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'
const TOGGLE_TODO = 'TOGGLE_TODO'
const SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER = 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER'
const OWNEDBY = 'OWNEDBY_ADMIN'


export function addTodo (text) {
  return { type: ADD_TODO, text }
}

export function toggleTodo (index) {
  return { type: TOGGLE_TODO, index }
}

export function setVisibilityFilter (filter) {
  return { type: SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER, filter }
}

export function setOwner (role) {
    return {type: OWNEDBY, role}
}


/*
 * reducers
 */

const VisibilityFilters = {
  SHOW_ALL: 'SHOW_ALL',
  SHOW_COMPLETED: 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
  SHOW_ACTIVE: 'SHOW_ACTIVE'
}

const { SHOW_ALL } = VisibilityFilters 

function visibilityFilter(state = SHOW_ALL, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return action.filter

    default:
      return state
  }
}


function setOwner(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case OWNEDBY :
      return action.role

    default :
      return state;
  }

}


function todos(state = [], action) { 

  switch (action.type) {

    case ADD_TODO:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]

    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      return state.map((todo, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
          return Object.assign({}, todo, {
            completed: !todo.completed
          })
        }
        return todo
      })

    default:
      return state
  }
}

import { combineReducers } from 'redux' //going round and round with this part, putting it everywhere
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ //this is super ugly
  visibilityFilter,
  todos,
  setOwner
});
```

I think it makes sense to put actions and reducers in the same file, and have 1 of these for each widget on your site, maybe in its own folder alongside its accompanying component, but I cant get it to work.

Comment: I don't see that you are exporting the `rootReducer` from `reducer.js`

Comment: This will not work well for a complex application. If the state would be private a to certain widget there is no need to use redux at all. You could store the state in the widget component's state. Usually when complexity grows you will find yourself acting on actions that are in a different file because you initially thought they "belong" to another reducer. In fact, actions do not belong to reducers at all. The key advantage of redux is that state isn't owned by a certain component so there shouldn't be an "accompanying" component.

Comment: So are you asking why visibilityFilter throws an error or a way to organise redux reducers and action creators or both?

Comment: Both. I think the error is from my misunderstanding of import / export.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the way I would organize the files in order for the application to consume Actions effectively in Reducers.
The index.js would look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Notice App.js is inside the components folder and my app.js would look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';

import WidgetList from '../containers/widget-list';
import WidgetDetail from '../containers/widget-detail';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <VisibilityFilter />
        <ToDos />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In your reducer.js this part:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux' //going round and round with this part, putting it everywhere
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ //this is super ugly
  visibilityFilter,
  todos,
  setOwner
```

is the only part that makes sense to me, but you want to make sure that code is generating usable state for your application by creating the appropriate component within react. You need a key and value within

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ });
```

For example:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({

    widgets: WidgetsReducer,
    activeWidget: ActiveWidget
});

export default rootReducer;
```

These action creators:

```
export function addTodo (text) {
  return { type: ADD_TODO, text }
}

export function toggleTodo (index) {
  return { type: TOGGLE_TODO, index }
}

export function setVisibilityFilter (filter) {
  return { type: SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER, filter }
}

export function setOwner (role) {
    return {type: OWNEDBY, role}
}
```

I would organize into an index.js file in the actions folder. For this:

```
function visibilityFilter(state = SHOW_ALL, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return action.filter

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I would organize it like this:

```
export default function(state, action){
   switch(action.type) {
      case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER':
        return action.payload;
   }
   return state;
}
```